# Excel Custom Ribbon Separators

Tags: excel

I was looking for a way to insert vertical separators into a custom ribbon in Excel 2010, which seems to be problematic for everyone.

Comment: This is not about coding, but the general use of the app.  It does not belong here.  It belongs on www.SuperUser.com

Answer (score 1):

Here goes.. This applies to Excel 2010 on.

1. Enter the 'Customize Ribbon' window. Create a new tab, (this creates a blank custom ribbon), and also creates a default group within the tab, which you can rename, and add buttons/macros to.
2. Make sure your new tab is selected in the 'Customize Ribbon' window.
3. Add another group or maybe more, (I have 4 groups in my ribbon)
4. Insert your buttons/macros into each of these groups
5. Click 'OK' and voila, you now have vertical separators.
6. Export the customizations using the 'Import/Export' button at the bottom of the window, to the default file name ('Excel Customizations.exportedUI'), this is an XML file.
7. Edit this file with a text editor, look for the phrase 'autoScale="true" (there is one for each group), this will determine if your buttons are large or small, if this is set to true then its possible some buttons will be large and some small, change it to 'autoScale="false" to show small buttons.
8. Import your file back into the 'Customize Ribbon' window, click 'OK' to overwrite any existing customizations.

By default, ribbon groups are separated by a "vertical separator", you can have one or more buttons/macros within each group, evry group will have its own label across the bottom. It seems like everyone is trying to put all their buttons/macros into one group within their custom tab ribbon which is why they can't insert separators individually. This is the ONLY way you can have separators in your custom ribbon.